# Firefox ignoring CSS font-weight property

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, font-face

Not sure if I'm using the correct process for displaying a font that has 3 weights - `normal`, `bold` and `lighter` - but, it seems to work in most browsers expect Firefox.

Firefox seems to be using `font-weight: lighter`; as default?

How the fonts appear in Chrome is what I'm after.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lovelo';
    src: url('../fonts/lovelo.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/lovelo.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo.svg#loveloblack') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'lovelo';
    src: url('../fonts/lovelo-bold.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/lovelo-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-bold.svg#loveloblack') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'lovelo';
    src: url('../fonts/lovelo-light.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/lovelo-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-light.svg#loveloblack') format('svg');
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

[working example](http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using the actual numbers for the font-weight. 
400 is the same as font-weight: normal. 
700 is the same as font-weight: bold.
100, 200, or 300 are the additional values. You would have to choose one that is the effect you want.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I came across using a numerical value for font-weight this evening when checking a Mozilla forum but still came up short when try to use 400 for normal. If I remove the 'lighter' font-face, both normal and bold work. Including 'lighter' throws it in Firefox for some reason!?!

Comment: `lighter` is not a valid value for `font-weight` in `@font-face` rules.  See <http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-fonts/#descdef-font-weight> for the spec.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the other @font-face styles are simply being over written by the last one.

Basically `font-weight: lighter;` is being used because it appears last in a list of three rules with equal specificity.

I would trim it down to one @font-face and place the font weights on your text elements like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lovelo';
    src: url('../fonts/lovelo-light.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/lovelo-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-light.svg#loveloblack') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
}

p{
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

Comment: If I use a single font-face, such as lovelo-lighter, surely the 'normal' typeface won't show? Or have I misread your suggestion? :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @user1640021

I experimented a little further with expressing a numerical value for `font-weight` and it seems to of done the trick in Firefox!

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lovelo';
    src: url('../fonts/lovelo.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/lovelo.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo.svg#lovelo') format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'lovelo';
    src: url('../fonts/lovelo-bold.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/lovelo-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-bold.svg#lovelo-bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'lovelo';
    src: url('../fonts/lovelo-light.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/lovelo-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/lovelo-light.svg#lovelo-light') format('svg');
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

[working example](http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/)

Comment: @apaul34208 but I'm using 3 different fonts??