# Why is Firefox Selecting the wrong font weight from my font-face options?

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, font-face

I've been using [Source Sans Pro](https://github.com/adobe/source-sans-pro) and [Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe/source-code-pro) on my [sites](http://theory.so), and it looks great in Safari and Chrome. In Firefox, however, it looks like the wrong font weight is being used, as the weight is much lighter (and harder to read) in Firefox. My [`@font-face` declarations](https://github.com/theory/theory-theme/blob/master/sass/base/_typography.scss) look like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    src: url('/fonts/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/sourcesanspro-regular-webfont.svg#source_sans_proregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
    src: url('/fonts/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/sourcesanspro-light-webfont.svg#source_sans_prolight') format('svg');
    font-weight: lighter; // light
    font-style: normal;

}
```

See [the file](https://github.com/theory/theory-theme/blob/master/sass/base/_typography.scss) for the full declaration. Is there something about my declarations that causes Firefox to select the wrong file when displaying the `normal` size?

Comment: I am not convinced that relative font weights can be used to select a font. The @font-face rule won't know what your weight is relative to! E.G. if the current weight is bold, then "ligher" is supposed to select the "normal" font, right? So in other words, You should test with `font-weight:200` (or the particular weight you're after) in both the @font-face rule and in the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17414815/79202), it looks as though Firefox uses the last declared `@font-face` for a given style to display the content. The last face I had defined for the `normal` style had a weight of `light`, so that was the one Firefox used. The solution is to use the [numeric weights](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) in the `@font-face` declarations, as I have now done [here](https://github.com/theory/theory-theme/commit/6901c7e8c0c1063de661e97e2eb0d7b76f7b8058). Then it properly uses the normal weight where appropriate.

Comment: Firefox uses the last `@font-face` with a matching `font-style`, `font-weight`, and `font-stretch`.  The default value of `font-weight` is `normal`.  In a font descriptor, `lighter` is not a valid value for `font-weight` according to <http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-fonts/#descdef-font-weight>.  So the second descriptor has a syntax error, and ends up using the default value of `normal`, which means it overrides the first font descriptor.  Also, note that in this case the console in Firefox says "Error in parsing value for 'font-weight'.  Skipped to next declaration." on the buggy line.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Safari use webkit as their rendering engine. (Chrome has now moved to Blink that uses a subset of webkit). Firefox on the other hand uses gecko. So yeah, that's pretty much the reason why we need to test webpages with different browsers.

As for your question, I guess this will help: http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/font-rendering-ugly-in-firefox-but-beautiful-in-webkit/

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Also, as the OP already said that Firefox has a different result than Safari and Chrome, it's clear that they are already testing in different browsers. So even as a comment, this would be redundant.

Comment: @MrLister I had already provided a link to solve the OP's problem

Comment: Actually, this answer provided enough context that I was able to find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17415120/79202), which suggested the actual solution.